# Windows Server 2003/Terminal Services - DLL Caching?

Tags: windows-server-2003, cache, dll

Does Windows Server 2003 cache specific DLLs on a per-user basis when in a terminal server environment?

**Back-Story:**

We recently had to update some DLLs for our application, and a couple clients are still experiencing the issue that the update was to resolve.  The build number of the DLL changed, but obviously the name did not.  So I'm trying to figure out if these users had a cached version of the old DLL somewhere in their profile.

Comment: No one has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Although a bit late, I am guessing that the cache is held under %Systemroot%\System32\Dllcache. This can safely be deleted (not the folder but the files itself) and repopulate.

There isn't a specified location for the user DLL but best bet is to do a quick scan under %USERPROFILE% for *.dll and see what comes up.